# IOS: Strategy for playing full screen video at correct aspect ratio on both iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, video, fullscreen

I'm developing an IOS app that will support both iPhone and iPad.  I want to play a full-screen background video, but the same file will either be stretched or cutoff on larger or smaller screens.

What is the best strategy for making sure the video plays with the correct aspect ratio?  Do you just bundle them both and use code to distinguish?

It doesn't seem correct to bundle different videos for each possible aspect ratio.  Wouldn't the app bundle size get out of hand?  Is there a way to package the correct one for iPad vs iPhone somehow?